# Linux shell pipe syntax

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I am implementing a program that simulates the Linux shell and I need to implement expressions with multiple pipes - but I am not sure what's considered legal or how to handle a few things, for example:

- Is pipe as the last character in the command legal? When I try it in the Linux shell it displays really weird behavior - after pressing enter it shows a new line with > in the beginning. I am not sure what does this mean as to the legality of the command?
- How to handle several consecutive pipes? For example ls -l ||||| grep 7
  it seems the shell just works as usual and ignores the redundant pipes but I am nit sure. Would like some help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about _what_ to program, not _how_ to program. The [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for asking about the grammar of (ba)sh.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a *single* Linux shell (but several shells). The most common one is [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), but you can use some other like [zsh](http://zsh.org/) (which I am using interactively) or [fish](http://fishshell.com), or even [scsh](http://scsh.net/) -or [es](https://wryun.github.io/es-shell/)- which has a quite different syntax. And all of them don't share exactly the same syntax and don't report the same errors.

There is however a standard, [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), which defines the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) (as a technical document in English):

> The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [!] command1 [ | command2 ...]
> ```
>
> The standard output of command1 shall be connected to the standard input of command2.

As you can see, you can't end your command with a `|`.

Your interactive bash shell is giving a different prompt when an incomplete line has been input.  It is using the [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library for interactive editable input (and completion).

All the shells I know on Linux are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you could study their source code. [`sash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) is a quite simple shell whose code is quite readable (but a bit buggy); it lacks most of the interactive facilities (notably [auto-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete)) of more sophisticated shells.

You'll need to understand most of [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) before coding your own shell...

For a homework, you probably can afford giving an error message on the first encountered error.